# Capturing get request which is delivered in URL

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutterwebviewplugin

HI guys i am new to flutter and trying to build app on the rest API which returns a redirection URL in response for payment purpose, and after completion of the payment it provides a call back on the return URL that i have passed in the request can any one help me to figure out how can i route to the return URL after completing my web view process as i cannot find any url scheme for the return part so.

Sample Request API:

Request

{
"client_id": "abcd",
"redirection_url": "**{return URL that is passed to capture the transaction response.}**",
"amount": 300,
"order_id": "dsdsassddddddd3"
}

Created an app just want to handle the Query param that are returned to certain URL on webview.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you may need to use WebHooks as the server has no way of just responding unless you configure a webhook. Look at Stripe for example https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Comment: i tried but the webview is not closing as our server provide response on return url it stucks on the issue webpage not found instead of redirecting because it requires a URL to flow to the final page.